# C - using enums to send error messages to user?

Tags: c, error-handling, enums

I made an array based Stack data structure in C.

Furthermore I wanted to implement error handling to allow other people to use this class as well for there own uses, but the best I have come up is for the method to return an enum and then have the user send the value into a "printErrorMessage" function where it to prints a message to terminal.

```
    /**enum with all the possible error messages**/
    typedef enum stackError_t {SUCESS, FAILED_MEMORY_ALLOCATION, FAILED_STACK_DOUBLEUP, NEGATIVE_VALUE, STACK_EMPTY}STACK_ERROR_MESSAGE;

   /**prints error message to terminal**/
   void printErrorMessage(STACK_ERROR_MESSAGE *message){
      switch(*message){
        case SUCESS : printf("Nothing went wrong!");break;
        case FAILED_MEMORY_ALLOCATION : printf("Not enough memory!");break;
        case FAILED_STACK_DOUBLEUP : printf("Stack has failed to doubleUP!");break;
        case NEGATIVE_VALUE : printf("Negative Value should have not been entered!");break;
        case STACK_EMPTY : break;
    }
    /**example method that can return an error**/
    STACK_ERROR_MESSAGE makeStack(Stack **stack, const uint32_t length, const uint32_t bytes)
```

The other was is for users to pass in a enum pointer to the function

```
    void * popStack(Stack *stack, STACK_ERROR_MESSAGE *message)
```

and then call "printErrorMessage" function if anything goes wrong.

I was hoping to get better ideas then to use a enum for this error handling as it seems a little clunky. Plus I would need to check in every method if the Stack pointer has been initialized and add an error enum like "STACK_NOT_INITIALIZED".

TLDR - What other ways are there to do error handling in C? And if you use enums what types of errors would you add?

And I apologize in advance if this question has been asked.

Thank You for your time.

Regards,
Dagar

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `char[][]` array (an array of *strings*) aligned to `STACK_ERROR_MESSAGE` enum, so that whenever you get an error you are able to use the enum item as an index to access the desired string:

```
/**enum with all the possible error messages**/
typedef enum stackError_t
{
    SUCCESS,
    FAILED_MEMORY_ALLOCATION,
    FAILED_STACK_DOUBLEUP,
    NEGATIVE_VALUE,
    STACK_EMPTY,
    MAX_STACK_ERROR
} STACK_ERROR_MESSAGE;

static const char *stackErrorStrings[]
{
    "SUCCESS",
    "FAILED_MEMORY_ALLOCATION",
    "FAILED_STACK_DOUBLEUP",
    "NEGATIVE_VALUE",
    "STACK_EMPTY",
    "MAX_STACK_ERROR"
};

/**prints error message to terminal**/
void printErrorMessage(STACK_ERROR_MESSAGE *message)
{
    if( message && *message > SUCCESS && *message < MAX_STACK_ERROR){
        printf("Stack failed with error %s\n", stackErrorStrings[*message]);
    }
}
```

This method is mainly suitable for those situations in which the errors don't vary too much during the lifetime of the software, because the enum and the string array have to be kept aligned.

As you can see, it allows a "standardization" of the error message string (in which I chose to print nothing in case of success).